# A Countable Basis and Countably Locally Finite Collections

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

> Show that if $X$ has a countable basis, a collection $\mathcal{A}$ of subsets of $X$ is countably locally finite if and only if it is countable.

I am going to give my proof of the $\impliedby$ implication first. Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a countable collection of subsets of $X$. Then we can enumerate them by $\Bbb{N}$ likeso: $\mathcal{A} = \{A_n \mid n \in \Bbb{N}\}$. But then $\mathcal{A} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{A_n\}$, where $\{A_n\}$ is locally finite since any given open set can intersect at most one set in $\{A_n\}$, and hence, intersect finitely many sets in $\{A_n\}$. This means that $\mathcal{A}$ is countably locally finite.

<s>For the other direction, I am having a little trouble. A countably locally finite set can be written as a countable union of locally finite sets, so it seems that it suffices to show any locally finite collection is countable. Let $\mathcal{A}$ be any such collection. As with most arguments about cardinality, it seems that my best option is to construct a function $f : \mathcal{B} \to \mathcal{A}$ that is surjective. Here's an attempt. Assume that $A \in \mathcal{A}$ is not empty. Then there exists $a \in A$, and since $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $a \in B$, so that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$. So we might define $f(B) = A$ such that $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ (note: there could be may sets in $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying this, so perhaps this won't work...?) Is it well-defined? Well, if $B=B'$, then $\emptyset \neq A \cap B = A \cap B'$, which I guess means that $f(B) = f(B')$ (?). But by definition, this is surjective, so $|\Bbb{N}| = |\mathcal{B}| \ge |\mathcal{A}|$, implying that $\mathcal{A}$ is countable.</s>

As the periodic question marks in the above paragraph indicate, I don't feel terribly comfortable with some parts of the proof. Another thing is, I don't seem to use $\mathcal{A}$'s local finiteness anywheree. Is there a way of clarifying the proof? If it's incorrect, is there a way of fixing it? If not, I could use a hint on how to prove the theorem.

**EDIT:** Hold on! I may have a proof. Just give me a few minutes to type it up.

Okay. My proof is slightly inspired by Henno's answer given [here](http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-a-topologist/2009/3349.htm), although I didn't read the entire proof until I came up with my own, because I wanted to try to solve the problem own my own as much as possible (indeed, the only thing I saw in the link was his definition of $I(n)$). Here is my second attempt at proving the "$\implies$" implication, which is I believe is slightly different from Henno's since I don't do a proof by contradiction.

First, let $\mathcal{A} = \{A_i \mid i \in I\}$ be some locally finite collection. We want to show that $I$ is countable. For each $n \in \Bbb{N}$, define $I(n) = \{i \in I \mid A_i \cap B_n \neq \emptyset \}$. Clearly the union of these sets is contained in $I$. Suppose that $i \in I$. Then given $A_i \neq \emptyset$, there exists $a_i \in A_i$; and since $\mathcal{B} = \{B_n \mid n \in \Bbb{N}\}$ is a basis, there exists an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $a_i \in B_n$, which implies that $i \in I(n)$. Hence $I = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I(n)$, so that we need only prove that $I(n)$ is countable. To this end, let $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and let $x \in B_n$. Since $\mathcal{A}$ is locally finite, there exists a basis element $B_{x_k}$ containing $x$ that intersects only finitely many elements in $\mathcal{A}$. Hence, $\{B_{x_k}\}$ is a cover of $B_n$, each of which intersects only finitely many sets in $\mathcal{A}$; moreover, since $\mathcal{B}$ is countable, $\{B_{k_x}\}$ must also be countable and hence can be enumerated likeso: $\{B_{\alpha_k} \mid k \in \Bbb{N} \}$. Now, if $A_i \cap B_n \neq \emptyset$, then it must also intersect a set in the cover of $B_n$, which means that $I(n) \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty I(\alpha_k)$. Seeing as the latter set is a countable union of finite sets, which is makes it countable, $I(n)$ is als countable.

How does this sound?

Comment: Trying to guess what you could mean by "countably locally finite". Do you mean $\sigma$-locally finite, by any chance?

Comment: @bof Possibly...Here's the definition my book (Munkres' Topology) gives: A collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ is said to be **countably locally finite** if $\mathcal{B}$ can be written as the countable union of collections $\mathcal{B}_n$, each of which is locally finite.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of $\sigma$-locally finite. Apparently some person named Munkres has written a book on topology with a lot of nonstandard terminology.

Comment: $I(n)$ could be large for some $n$. You cannot a priori show they're all countable. But there are enough $I(n)$ that are finite and union up to $I$. This is what my proof below does, essentially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slight refinement of the proof of mine you linked to:

If $\mathcal{A}$ is locally finite (and consisting of non-empty sets WLOG) and $\{B_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a countable base for $X$, define

$$I = \big\{n \in \mathbb{N}: \mathcal{A}_n:= \{A \in \mathcal{A}: B_n \cap A \neq \emptyset \} \text{ is finite }\big\}$$

This is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ so certainly a countable set.
Then I claim that $$\mathcal{A} = \bigcup_{n \in I} \mathcal{A}_n$$

which is a countable union of finite sets making $\mathcal{A}$ at most countable.

All $\mathcal{A}_n \subseteq \mathcal{A}$ by definition so one inclusion is obvious. If $B \in \mathcal{A}$, then choose $x \in B$ and we have a neighbourhood $O_x$ of $x$ such that $\{A \in \mathcal{A}: O_x \cap A \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite by local finiteness of $\mathcal{A}$. We can find some $n_x$ such that $x \in B_{n_x} \subseteq O_x$ as the $B_n$ form a base, and so then $\mathcal{A}_{n_x} = \{A \in \mathcal{A}: A \cap B_{n_x} \neq \emptyset \}$ is finite. This means that $n_x \in I$ by definition of $I$, and $B \in \mathcal{A}_{n_x}$ as well, showing the other inclusion.

Variations of this idea will show that also a point-countable family is at most countable e.g.

Comment: Firstly $mathcal{A}$ is countably locally finite. However you consider it just to be locally finite. Could you give more details what is the set $I$? I am a bit lost.

Comment: @ZFR if a collection is countably locally finite, it is a countable union of locally finite families and my proof gives that a locally finite family is countable. A countable union of countable families is countable so my case is sufficient. $I$ is clearly defined I think; what is unclear about it?

Comment: Yes I got the definition of $I$. But how did you come up with it? I have tried many hours to solve this problem and failed.

Comment: @ZFR Trying things after studying several proofs on locally finite families. I had a whole course only on such covering properties (paracompactness variations and theorems on such properties ). There are a lot of similar ideas used in such proofs. Recurrent themes. So experience, eventually.

Comment: Probably you are right! Experience matters. I am learning topology for the last 2-3 month.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to fill in some of the steps left out above for others if they didn't understand it, because I had a hard time.

$A = \bigcup{C_{N}}$. Where $C_{N}$ is a locally finite collection. Note that if $C_{N}$ is countable collection, then by simple analysis $A$ is a countable collection since then $A$ would be a countable union of a countable number of sets. Thus, the problem is that $C_{N}$ may not be a countable collection.

Since $X$ is second countable, $X = \bigcup{B_{i}}$; where a countable set of indices $i$ can be used.

Not every basis element may intersect $C_{N}$ in only finitely many places. Thus, we need some sort of method to remove the bad basis elements for my proof to work.

Since $X$ can be written as the union of non-empty basis elements, every $x \in X$ is contained within a basis element $B_{i}$. The local finiteness of $C_{N}$ implies some neighborhood U of x must intersect $C_{N}$ in finitely many sets. If the neighborhood U is contained within $B_{i}$, then pick a basis element $B_{j} \subset U \subset B_{i}$ that contains x and throw out the original basis element $B_{i}$. Otherwise relabel $B_{i} = B_{j}$. Then for sure $B_{j}$ intersects $C_{N}$ in finitely many sets or zero. Since we still have $x \in B_{j}$, and $x$ was arbitrary in $X$, the space $X = \bigcup{B_{j}}$ where the basis elements $B_{j}$ intersects $C_{N}$ in finitely many sets or zero sets.

Define $A_{j} = B_{j}\bigcap{C_{N}} = \bigcup_{M=1}^{<\infty}{\{C_{M}\}}$. The $C_{M}$ are the finite sets that $B_{j}$ intersects $C_{N}$ in. If its zero sets that they intersect in, then just leave $A_{j}$ empty for now.

Every element $y \in C \in C_{N}$ lies in X, obviously because $C$ are subsets of $X$. Then we know at least one basis element $B_{j}$ in our refined collection intersects any arbitrary $C$ of $C_{N}$; otherwise $C$ is empty because we could just pick $x$ to be in C, and find the $B_{j}$ that contains x and only intersects $C_{N}$ finitely. Thus taking the union over basis elements: $\bigcup{A_{j}} \supset C_{N}$.

Hence, we have that $C_{N}$ is at most a countable number of sets because $C_{N} \subset \bigcup{A_{j}} = \bigcup{\{\bigcup_{M=1}^{<\infty}{\{C_{M}}\}\}_{j}}$ which is a countable union of a finite numbers of sets.

Knowing this, we must have $A = \bigcup{C_{N}}$ is a countable union of a at most countable number of sets.